# Command to alter the listener port in websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

```
alter listener(QM) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1718)
```

This is the command am using. Please suggest if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would expect that command to work as long as you have a listener named 'QM' which you want to alter to listen on TCP port 1718.

DISPLAY LISTENER(*) ALL

Will give you all the information on all the listener objects you currently have defined.

Comment: If you alter a listener that is already running, changes will take effect only after you stop and start the listener again.